# OnErrorResponse issue when using volley

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm using volley for my networking and I keep getting a strange error in my `NetworkManager` class.

`OnErrorResponse` keeps getting flagged as an error by android studio:

[image]

However the project builds and works fine with no errors.
I've cleaned and rebuilt my project as well as invalidating caches and restarting android studio.

My full request method:

```
public void postRequest(String url, JSONObject requestBody, final Context mContext, final NetworkListener<JSONObject> networkListener) {


    Log.d(TAG + " >>> REQUEST URL", url);
    Log.d(TAG + " >>> REQUEST BODY", requestBody.toString());

    try {
        if (!url.contains("login")) {
            requestBody.put("auth", addAuthToRequest());
            Log.d(TAG + " >>> REQUEST BODY AUTH", requestBody.toString());
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, requestBody, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            Log.d(TAG + " >>> RESPONSE", response.toString());
            try {
                if (response.getString("message").equals("Invalid session token")) {
                    handleInvalidSessionToken(mContext);
                } else {
                    networkListener.onResult(response);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            networkListener.onErrorResult(error);
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(60000, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    requestQueue.add(request);
}
```

Comment: which version of volley are you using ? @ MichaelStoddart

Comment: @A.N.T im using the official gradle import from google com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0

Comment: import this com.android.volley.VolleyError; @ MichealStoddart

Comment: version num? @A.N.T

Comment: 1.0.0 @ MichealStoddart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out my issue was duplicate methods that I only found when I tried to build an APK.

I was using the official volley lib and a 3rd party one called VolleyPlus for image uploads.

I removed the official repo and re did my imports and this got rid of my errors.

Before:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4'
}
```

After:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4'
}
```

Since VolleyPlus has all of volleys methods and more, I figured I could delete the official lib and just use [VolleyPlus](https://github.com/DWorkS/VolleyPlus).